# Finding the limit of the sequence $\{n/(1+ \sqrt n)\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was given the following question:

Find the limit of the sequence
$$\left\{\frac n{1+ \sqrt n}\right\}$$

where the sequence goes from $n = 1$ to $n \to \infty$.

The worked solution provided by my tutor divided the numerator and denominator by $n$ to get

$$\left\{\frac 1{1+ {\frac 1 {\sqrt n}}}\right\}$$ and ended up giving the limit of 1.

However, after I solved it and graphed it, I realised that the limit is infinity and hence the sequence is divergent.

Can someone please clarify if I am right or wrong? If I am wrong, can someone please explain what I need to do to correct my mistake.

Comment: The division of the denominator by $n$ was done incorrectly. Should get $1/((1/n)+(1/\sqrt n))$.

Comment: $\frac n {1+\sqrt n} \geq \frac n {2\sqrt n}=\frac  1 2 \sqrt n \to \infty$.

Comment: Often, $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$. Is that what you mean, or are the braces to be considered like parentheses?

Comment: @robjohn the braces are to be considered as parentheses. This is the notation we were instructed to use in class :)

Comment: $\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}-1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}+1}$. The sum of the last two terms tends to $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS you say, the series diverges, since with a simple rearrangement, we obtain $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1/\sqrt{n}+1}$, which limit clearly diverges.